# Pandas 'multi-index' issue in merging dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge, multi-index

I have a panel dataset as `df`

```
stock    year    date   return
VOD      2017    01-01   0.05
VOD      2017    01-02   0.03
VOD      2017    01-03   0.04
...      ...     ...     ....
BAT      2017    01-01   0.05
BAT      2017    01-02   0.07
BAT      2017    01-03   0.10
```

so I use this code to get the mean and skewness of the return for each stock in each year.

```
df2=df.groupby(['stock','year']).mean().reset_index()
df3=df.groupby(['stock','year']).skew().reset_index()
```

`df2` and `df3` look fine.

`df2` is like (after I change the column name)

```
stock    year   mean_return
 VOD     2017    0.09
 BAT     2017    0.14
 ...      ...    ...
```

`df3` is like (after I change the column name)

```
stock    year   return_skewness
 VOD     2017    -0.34
 BAT     2017    -0.04
 ...      ...    ...
```

The problem is when I tried to merge `df2` and `df3` by using

```
want=pd.merge(df2,df2, on=['stock','year'],how='outer')
```

python gave me

```
'The column label 'stock' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.'
```

, which confuses me alot.

I can use  `want = pd.merge(df2,df3, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')` to merge `df2` and `df3`, but after that i have to rename the columns as column names are in parentheses.

Is there any convenient way to merge `df2` and `df3` ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better is use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for specify aggregate function in list and column for aggregation after function:

```
df3 = (df.groupby(['stock','year'])['return']
         .agg([('mean_return','mean'),('return_skewness','skew')])
         .reset_index())
print (df3)
  stock  year  mean_return  return_skewness
0   BAT  2017     0.073333         0.585583
1   VOD  2017     0.040000         0.000000
```

Your solution should be changed with remove `reset_index`, `rename` and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), also is specified column `return` for aggregate:

```
s2=df.groupby(['stock','year'])['return'].mean().rename('mean_return')
s3=df.groupby(['stock','year'])['return'].skew().rename('return_skewness')

df3 = pd.concat([s2, s3], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df3)
  stock  year  mean_return  return_skewness
0   BAT  2017     0.073333         0.585583
1   VOD  2017     0.040000         0.000000
```

EDIT:

If need aggregate all numeric columns remove list after `groupby` first and then use `map` with `join` for flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df)
  stock  year   date  return  col
0   VOD  2017  01-01    0.05    1
1   VOD  2017  01-02    0.03    8
2   VOD  2017  01-03    0.04    9
3   BAT  2017  01-01    0.05    1
4   BAT  2017  01-02    0.07    4
5   BAT  2017  01-03    0.10    3

df3 = df.groupby(['stock','year']).agg(['mean','skew'])
print (df3)
              return                 col          
                mean      skew      mean      skew
stock year                                        
BAT   2017  0.073333  0.585583  2.666667 -0.935220
VOD   2017  0.040000  0.000000  6.000000 -1.630059

df3.columns = df3.columns.map('_'.join)
df3 = df3.reset_index()
print (df3)
  stock  year  return_mean  return_skew  col_mean  col_skew
0   BAT  2017     0.073333     0.585583  2.666667 -0.935220
1   VOD  2017     0.040000     0.000000  6.000000 -1.630059
```

Your solutions should be changed:

```
df2=df.groupby(['stock','year']).mean().add_prefix('mean_')
df3=df.groupby(['stock','year']).skew().add_prefix('skew_')


df3 = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df3)
  stock  year  mean_return  mean_col  skew_return  skew_col
0   BAT  2017     0.073333  2.666667     0.585583 -0.935220
1   VOD  2017     0.040000  6.000000     0.000000 -1.630059
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael  . I also tried to apply `concat` to merge two dataset. However, some columns end up in parentheses and I have to manually change the column names. Do you happen to know how to solve this ?

Comment: @FlyUFalcon - sure, so there is more column like `return` ?

Comment: Yes. the columns of df2 changed to `(stock,)` `(year,)` and `(return,)`  . So I have to change and delete some columns. The dataset I showed is a simplified one. I have quite a few columns in my dataset. Thanks

Comment: Thanks !  appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

A easier way to bypass this issue:

```
df2.to_clipboard(index=False)
df2clip=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')

df3.to_clipboard(index=False)
df3clip=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')
```

Then merge 2 df again:

```
pd.merge(df2clip,df3clip,on=['stock','year'],how='outer')
```