# Unable to perform arithmetic and sort operations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, arithmetic-expressions

I am unable to perform arithmetic operations but mentioning .values at the end of the object, I was able to perform it. However, I am unable to sort the dataset by column. Screenshot [arithmetic operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQUDY.png) [sorting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DNb0.png) attached.

Here is the data structure and info.
[Data Structure and info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0gEp.png)

```
grade   n_obs   n_good
A   74867   71970
B   136929  126170
C   125293  110909
D   76888   65040
E   35757   28793
F   13229   10037
G   3322    2398
```

As you can see all variables are either float or int but still, I have to use .values in order to perform any arithmetic operations.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Hi Ajay, this is related to the structure of your dataframe. Could you please post the structrure of the dataframe? Ideally in text format, inside your question?

Comment: Check this, might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828684/pandas-multi-index-issue-in-merging-dataframes

Comment: did you try this solutio[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56376895/10210389)n?